# How can CKEditor 4 be made to create links than can be clicked on?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

An HTML 'a' element can be clicked on to navigate to the target page if it has a 'contenteditable="false" attribute to cancel the 'contenteditable="true" property of the CKEditor's parent element, but there doesn't seem to be any way to make CKEditor 4 do this.